# Sort by number of occurrences in bash in groups

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to sort like this in bash?

Input:

```
1
2
3
1
1
2
```

Output:

```
1
1
1

2
2

3
```

I want to print most number of occurrences in groups with a blank new line in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
processThatProducesInput | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sort -k1,1nr |
while read -r n data; do
    for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do 
        echo "$data"
    done
    echo
done
```

First we sort the input. This is a lexical sort but it can be numeric if you want, it would only matter for groups of the same size: what order do you want those in?
Then we count each sorted group.
Then we sort by the size of the groups in descending order.
Then we re-output the sorted index, with the blank line as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk only:

```
$ awk ' {
    c[$0]++                                 # count char frequencies
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"   # starting with the biggest count
    for(i in c) {                           # for every char count
        printf "%s", (j==""?"":"\n")        # output empty line where needed
        for(j=1;j<=c[i];j++)                # count many times
            print i                         # ... print the char
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
1
1
1

2
2

3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `sort` and `awk`

```
sort file | awk 'p&&p!=$1{print FS}{p=$1}1'
```

Comment: Something more detailed: `sort file | awk '{ if(p!="" && p!=$1) {print ""}; {p=$1; print} }'`

Comment: This is not what OP is requesting. This only puts a blank line between groups. It does not sort by size of group.

Comment: You are right, this will not sort by size of group. I somehow missed that condition in request.